# Output user data to display class

Tags: java, class, methods

```
package developer;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Developer 
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String workType; // This will be either an app, or game
    String name;
    int pay;
    int weekPay;
    int hrsWorked;
    double tax;

    public Developer()
    {
        name  = "Ciaran";
    }

    Developer(String appType, String coderName)
    {
        workType = appType;
        name = coderName;
    }// End developer

    Developer(String appType, int pay) // Class to choose the pay rate depending on if it is a game or app  
    {
        System.out.println("Are you coding an app or a game? ");
        appType = console.next();

        if(appType == "app")
        {
            pay = 20;
        }
        if(appType == "game")
        {
            pay = 30;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter either 'app' or 'game' ");
        }   
    }// End developer

    Developer(int hrsWorked, double tax, int weekPay, int pay) // Class to choose the tax bracket which the developer is in
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter how many hours you have worked this week: ");
        hrsWorked = console.nextInt();

        weekPay = hrsWorked * pay;

        if(weekPay >= 865)
        {
            tax = 0.4;
        }
        else
        {
            tax = 0.21;
        }   


    }// End developer

    Developer(int weekPay, int tax) // Gets the pay after tax
    {
        weekPay = weekPay * tax;
    }// End developer



    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("This display method works");
        System.out.println("User: " + name);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Developer myDev = new Developer();

        myDev.display();
    } // End main

}// End public class developer
```

I am trying to get this program to ask the user what their name is; if they are developing a game or app and the amount of hours worked on it. With all this information I want to calculate how much the dev earns including tax. I cannot seem to get the `display()` method to ask the user the questions though and I have no idea what to do. I am hoping somebody out there can help me.

Comment: This won'r work `if(appType == "app")`. You have to compare string with `equals` i.e. `if ("app".equals(appType))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that could be done differently in your code, so let's break it down:

1.No need to make console static type, you can use:

```
private Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

2.weekPay is of type int, but your tax is double, if you don't want weekPay to be cast to integer, change it to:

```
double weekPay;
```

3.Later on, you are calculating weekPay after tax, so let's introduce a variable for that:

```
double weekPayAfterTax;
```

4.All these Developer() methods are constructors, and I think you are slightly confused here. Of course, you can have many constructors, but for us, let's keep only the no-params constructor:

```
public Developer() {
    name = "Ciaran";
    //you could initialise all the other variables here as well,
    //I'll leave it as an exercise for you :)
}
```

5.Let's create a method that will ask all the questions and set respective variables:

```
void setData() {
    //let's get the name
    System.out.print("What's your name: ");
    name = console.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Are you coding an app or a game? ");

    //since we want the user to enter 'app' or 'game'
    //we need to loop until we got these
    //we can do this by creating endless while loop,
    //which we will end when we have correct input
    while (true) {
        workType = console.next();

        if (workType.equals("app")) {
            pay = 20.0;

            //stop the loop
            break;
        }
        else if (workType.equals("game")) {
            pay = 30.0;

            //stop the loop
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Please enter either 'app' or 'game': ");
            //back to top
        }
    }

    //ok, we're out the loop, let's get number of hours
    System.out.print("Please enter how many hours you have worked this week: ");
    hrsWorked = console.nextInt();

    //calculate weekPay
    weekPay = hrsWorked * pay;

    if(weekPay >= 865) {
        tax = 0.4;
    }
    else {
        tax = 0.21;
    }

    //calculate pay after tax
    weekPayAfterTax = weekPay - weekPay * tax;
}
```

6.Let's update our display() method to show all the info:

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println("This display method works");
    System.out.println("User: " + name);
    System.out.println("Work type: " + workType);
    System.out.println("Pay: " + pay);
    System.out.println("Week pay: " + weekPay);
    System.out.println("Week pay after tax: " + weekPayAfterTax);
}
```

7.In your main method, you can finally create an instance of Developer class and get the data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Developer myDev = new Developer();

    myDev.setData();
    myDev.display();
}
```

The code above can be improved (such as checking if user entered number where it's expected), and your problem can of course be done differently, but here's the start.

Please check out some tutorials to learn the basics, such as [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html), or [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaIntroduction/article.html). Most of all, experiment and don't let others put you down for not understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

System.in will read input from the command line. You should wrap it with a java.util.Scanner and nextLine like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String user_input = scanner.nextLine();
```

Be sure to check

```
scanner.hasNextLine()
```

before continuing or you'll get an error.

Comment: Let's avoid the `== true` antipattern. :)

Comment: I just meant that the user needs to see if there is a next line before calling, but you're right.